# My for loop in python is supposed to read every line in this file and print out abbreviations of all the airports but is getting stuck

Tags: python, loops, file, for-loop

We are given a csv file called "us-airports.csv" that has the names and cities of about 30,000 airports across the US. We have to read the file and get an abbreviation for the name of each airport as well as an abbreviation for each city.

Here is my code:

```
file_in = open("us-airports.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8")
file_out = open("output1.csv", "w")

row = file_in.readlines()

city_abb=""
name_abb = ""
#define functions
def name_function(name):
    global name_abb
    name=name.split()
    for t in range(len(name)):
        if t < 2:
            name_abb = str(name[0][0]+name[1][0])
        else:
            name_abb = str(name[0][0]+name[1][0]+name[2][0])
    #name_abb = str(name[0][0]+name[1][0]+name[2][0])
    name_abb = name_abb.upper()
    return(name_abb)
   

def city_function(city):
    global city_abb
    letters=city[:3]
    city_abb=letters.upper()
    return(city_abb)

#Loop
for i in range(len(row)):
    row[i] = row[i].strip()
    items = row[i].split(",")
    city_function(items[1])
    name_function(items[0])
    #print(items[0]+" - "+items[1])
#Output
    file_out.write(str(items[0])+","+str(items[1])+","+str(city_abb)+","+str(name_abb)+"\n")
#These are just here to find where the function was stopping.
    print(i+1)
    print(str(items[0])+","+str(items[1])+","+str(city_abb)+","+str(name_abb)+"\n")

file_out.close()
file_in.close()
print("done")
```

It is getting stuck on the 1454th time through the loop in the name_function at this line:

```
if t < 2:
     name_abb = str(name[0][0]+name[1][0])
```

Here is a screenshot of what the csv file looks like.
[Selected row is where the program gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6il5.png)

Comment: Are you sure your input file is actually UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: My teacher gave us the file and said it was.

Comment: When you say it gets stuck, exactly what happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I'm getting a charmap error

Comment: Great, could you add the full stack trace of the error to the post please?

Comment: _"Getting stuck"_ suggests that your code is falling into an infinite loop, never exiting... something like that. If you're receiving an exception, may I recommend that you edit your question and copy/paste the exception in your question?.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\codes.py", line 41, in <module>
    file_out.write(str(items[0])+","+str(items[1])+","+str(city_abb)+","+str(name_abb)+"\n")
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0121' in position 45: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Thanks. So you need to use UTF-8 encoding in your output file. The default Windows encoding (cp1252) can't encode the ġ in Utqiaġvik.

Comment: Hope that fixes it - going forward, it's best on Stack Overflow to specifically include the stack trace in your question: we could probably have got to the solution super-quickly with that.